# What do you call someone who starts arguments for their own satisfaction?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I was wondering if there is a word used to describe someone who starts arguments just because they get enjoyment/satisfaction out of it. And I don't mean a friendly debate I mean actual arguments, like a fight. I feel like there is a word for it but I can't think of it and if there is no word then I am going to make one for it :). P.S. "Devil's Advocate" is not the word I am looking for.

Comment: *argumentative*

Comment: An “argument clinician” especially those who argue on their spare time.

Comment: An **instigator**

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or an adjective? We'll get closer to your meaning if you edit in an example sentence of where you'd use the word, with a ___ where the word would go. If you're open to adjectives, there are a lot to choose from—belligerent, pugnacious, contentious, combative, fighty, etc.—so you might want to add more details to help narrow it down.

Comment: One suitable noun might be **controversialist** — one who is fond of or given to controversy or disputation, according to both Merriam-Webster and American Heritage dictionaries.

Comment: obnoxious or better yet, asshole.

Comment: I've always called these people "shit-disturbers," but I've never needed to upgrade it to a more formal or professional context. According to Wiktionary, it's Canadian slang.  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shit_disturber

Answer (score 3):

I'll tell you what I use.

See **firebrand** defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/firebrand) as

> one that creates unrest or strife (as in aggressively promoting a cause)

There are also simple words such as **agitator, trouble maker, rabble-rouser.**

Answer (score 1):

It may not *quite* be the word you are looking for, but pretty close...

**Pugnacious**.

It means [inclined to quarrel or fight readily; quarrelsome](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pugnacious).

Answer (score 1):

A contrarian is someone who takes an opposing view, especially for the sake of being difficult, contentious or in opposition to the generally held view.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. A good first post which would benefit from linked references to support your claim.

Answer (score 1):

A *provocateur* is:

> a person who provokes trouble, causes dissension, or the like; agitator.

according to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/provocateur).

There is a lively discussion of the etymology at [Did Emma Goldman first use the term “provocateur”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/432063/3306).

Answer (score 0):

That would be a **disputatious person**. As [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disputatious#other-words) explains

> *Disputatious people* like to provoke arguments or find something to disagree about.

and it [defines](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disputatious) disputatious as

> 1a: inclined to dispute
>
> b: marked by disputation

> 2: provoking debate : CONTROVERSIAL